# Cassandra thrift Erlang insert

Tags: erlang, cassandra, thrift

I'm currently trying to get my head wrap around Cassandra/thrift with Erlang...

I have a Column Family named "mq" (as in message queue)...

I would like to have a row per user (with an user_id), each message would be a new column with timestamp for name and the message as the value.

Here's in Cassandra-cli what I'm doing :

```
create keyspace my_keyspace;
use my_keyspace;
create column family mq with comparator=UTF8Type and key_validation_class=UTF8Type;

%% Adding to user_id (00000001) the message "Hello World!" 
set mq['00000001']['1336499385041308'] = 'Hello Wold';
```

Everything works great with Cassandra-cli

However, When I'm trying to insert from Erlang, I'm running into some issue :

```
1>rr(cassandra_types).
2>{ok, C}=thrift_client_util:new("localhost", 9160, cassandra_thrift,[{framed, true}]).
3>thrift_client:call(C, 'set_keyspace', ["peeem"]).
4>thrift_client:call(C,'insert',["00000001",
                     #columnPath{column_family="mq"},
                     #column{name="1336499385041308", value="Hello World!"},
                     1
                     ]
                   ).
```

Here's the error :

```
{error,{bad_args,insert,
              ["00000001",
               #columnPath{column_family = "mq",super_column = undefined,
                           column = undefined},
               #column{name = "1336499385041308",value = "Hello World!",
                       timestamp = undefined,ttl = undefined},1]}}}
```

Any help would be appreciated...

**EDIT 1 :**

I have found out that it should be (as it works for someone else) :

```
thrift_client:call(C,'insert', ["00000001", #columnParent{column_family="mq"}, #column{name="123456",value="Hello World!"}, 2]).
```

Here's the related error message :

```
** exception error: no match of right hand side value {{protocol,thrift_binary_protocol,
                                                                 {binary_protocol,{transport,thrift_framed_transport,
                                                                                             {framed_transport,{transport,thrift_socket_transport,
                                                                                                                          {data,#Port<0.730>,infinity}},
                                                                                                               [],[]}},
                                                                                  true,true}},
                                                       {error,closed}}
     in function  thrift_client:send_function_call/3 (src/thrift_client.erl, line 83)
     in call from thrift_client:call/3 (src/thrift_client.erl, line 40)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I have found out what was the issue, or issues to be correct...

Here's my code in order to connect and insert...

```
rr(cassandra_types).
{ok, C}=thrift_client_util:new("localhost", 9160, cassandra_thrift,[{framed, true}]).
{C1, _} = thrift_client:call(C, 'set_keyspace', ["my_keyspace"]).
thrift_client:call(C1,'insert', ["00000001", #columnParent{column_family="mq"}, #column{name="1234567",value="Hello World !", timestamp=0}, 2]).
```

In fact We should insert into the new thrift_client that 'set_keyspace' returns... apparently for every call done through thrift a new thrift_client is generated and should be used.

Further more, We should use columnParent instead of columnPath (not sure why yet, it just works). And timestamp in the #column is mandatory...

I hope this helps someone else.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend checking out https://github.com/ostinelli/erlcassa instead of reinventing the Thrift-wrestling wheel.

Comment: Hi, and thank you for your answer. I am already aware of erlcassa, which is using CQL. Unfortunately CQL today does not fit my need, it is quite limited at the time we are talking. For example, it does not seems to insert columns that have not been described in the column family metadata. So my data model which will insert a new column per row for each message is not viable with CQL.